# Replace tags in place of words - spacy

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

I am trying to replace the sentence with their tags. I want tags to replace words and form as a sentence.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import spacy,en_core_web_sm
import textacy
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
sentence = 'The cat sat on the mat. the dog sleeps.'
doc = nlp(sentence)
for token in doc:
print(token.dep_)
```

output.

```
det
nsubj
ROOT
prep
det
pobj
punct
det
nsubj
ROOT
punct
```

Expected output:

```
det nsubj ROOT prep det pobj det punct det nsubj ROOT punct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
print(" ".join([token.dep_ for token in doc]))   #List comprehension
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. If you could be kind to see my sentence structure question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460078/sentence-structure-identification-spacy

Comment: Please accept ans if it solved your problem. And I am looking at the que if I can solve your problem.